# Is the sentence you are very true to your word when you said fear not for i am with you correct?

Tags: tense, verbs

Which one is correct?

> You were very true to your word when you said, "Fear not for i am with you."
>   You are very true to your word when you said, "Fear not for i am with you."

I'm not sure what the right word to use if it's "are" or "were".

Comment: You seem to have a few typos, especially with capitalization and "dear" instead of "fear".

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct because the tense of "were" matches the tense of "said."

By the way:

- The word "I" is always capitalized. "Fear not for I am with you."
- Your last sentence isn't correct. Any of these sentences would be correct:

  - I'm not sure if the right word to use is "are" or "were."
  - I'm not sure if "are" or "were" is the right word to use.
  - I'm not sure what the right word to use is.